# Inheritance is better or composition design pattern in this scenario?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, inheritance, interfaces

Design and implement Cash Register:

Given a number of items you will be required to calculate the total bill.
Items are charged for in a couple of different ways:

- A given price for each item, e.g. Boxes of Cheerios are $6.99 each
- A given price by weight, e.g. Apples are $2.49 per pound
- Items can go on sale where you might receive bulk discounts, e.g. Buy two get one free sales; Buy four get one free
- Coupons are available to get money off the bill when the total amount is above a threshold, e.g. $5 off when you spend $100 or
  more

**My answer: I am not sure how much is correct, or how I can improve it?!**

I attached my design based on C#, and the code can be view on https://github.com/mandanemedia/CashRegister.

I appreciated if you could help to understand Inheritance is better or Composition. Based on the given scenario the answer must have the following concrete classes:

- ProductSellByQuantity.cs
- ProductSellByQuantityInGroupSell.cs
- ProductSellByWeight.cs

As well as two objects ShoppingCart & ShoppingCartByCoupon or might be only a ShoppingCart object.

My goal is to make OO design skills & design pattern better.

Click on it to open in bigger size.
[image: ProductSellSection]
[image: ShoppingCart]

Comment: I used the strategy pattern to implement this kata. It worked out pretty well. I created an `PricingStrategy` interface and then implemented things like `PerPoundStrategy` and `XForXStrategy`. The hard part was actually to recalculate as each item was scanned, as the same UPC can be scanned "out of order" with another item(s) in between.

Comment: @RubberDuck - I've used the same approach in POS implementations too.  Having a list of objects that are given access to scan through your collection of real purchases and add additional virtual line items for discounts, shipping, taxes, and so on is a useful approach here.

Comment: Migrated from CodeReview. Interesting. Perhaps the rules should be amended to allow review of design. In this case it looks complete enough to benefit from a review.

Answer (score 2):

#### Premature Over-Engineering

For example, I assert that you do not need any of those `interface`s. If needed later, make them later.

An `interface` (the C# keyword kind) is for giving common behavior to unrelated classes and then handle objects polymorphically.

Think more carefully about what constitutes a more specific class. Think of what a shopping cart IS. Is a "coupon shopping cart" a more specific kind of cart, or is it simply an attribute in a cart?

Think more carefully about how things work together, in contrast to seeing everything as separate, distinct bits. A coupon is a logical part of calculating a price. `GetPrice` is simply a necessary "grunt" method in a product class.

"groupsale" is a volume discount. This is the same concept as a coupon. Both are discounts. Said another way, they are simply adjustments to the price. Therefore they are an integral part of calculating cost. They are not classes.

---

#### Too much `interface`

*Code to interfaces not implementation* does not mean make everything a (C# keyword) `interface`. Any class' set of public methods IS an interface.

Implementing interfaces instead of inheriting from an abstract class sets you up for lots of redundant implementation.

This is a grotesque (sorry) mis-application of the `Interface segregation` principle. I cannot see how `ISell` justifies itself as a distinct `interface`. I do not see `ISell` references being passed around. `GetPrice()` simply looks like it naturally belongs to a `ProductXXX` object; where its meaning is more clear inside of a functional class.

Ditto for the shopping cart.

---

#### Weight, Quantity Abstracted

Abstracted, I strongly suspect the multiple `ProductSellBy...` classes coallece into one.

These are simply values. And these values are used in calculation in the same way, i.e. `GetPrice() * Quantity()`  The fact that `quantity` represents countable things or weight can be captured by a separate property. You've already got an `enum` for this, make a property of that type in the `Product` class.

This abstraction does away with the motivation for the many interfaces and classes and your diagram will shrink by more than half I think.

---

#### DRY up redundant methods

Make an `abstract` class for your `Product`s.

---

#### `ShoppingCart coupon`

"By coupon" makes no sense as a shopping cart sub-class. A coupon is simply an adjustment to price calculation.

As above, get rid of those `interface`s and make an `abstract` class if you must sub-class `ShoppingCart`.

And when you think about it, a coupon is not really a special case. A cost is coupon-discounted the same way for any item, I assume. So that discount can be built in to the price calculation. This is accomodated by the coupon's default value that would represent no discount.